# EC2 .NET website installation error

Tags: .net, installation, amazon-ec2

I am trying to install my ASP.NET 3.5 website on EC2 windows instance and i get this error although i am running it under the admin user:

"You do not have sufficient privileges to complete this installation for all users of the machine. Log on as administrator and then retry this installation."

Answer (score 0):

if you ever get that error message when running an install and you’re already an Administrator then try changing the UAC settings to Never Notify.

To change your UAC settings:

1. Go to Start à Control Panel
2. Select User Accounts and Family Safety
3. Select User Accounts
4. Select Change User Account Control settings